# List Types of classes that inherit from another class

Tags: java

So, this is probably a simple question because I'm only missing a command here.
How can I list all the types of those classes that inherit from a specific class. Or formulated another way: How can I list the type of all child-classes from a class?

```
public class person {

    person()   
    {     
        listChilds(this);   
    } 
}
```

`listChilds` in this case would produce a list that would probably contain classes like `teacher`, `footballPlayer`, `student`, `plumber`, etc. The `getClass()` command of all the subclasses basically.

Is there actually a way to do this?

Comment: This is impossible. A superclass by definition does not know about what inherits from it. You would have to implement something manually.

Comment: on a similar note, it might have things outside the scope:  example.   Listing Children of Object would only list classes which are covered by the scope of imported material.

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: Given that it looks you are unexperienced, this definately sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? Most likely you are using the wrong tools to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah, to be honest that is probably the wrong tool to achieve it - thanks to all that answered. The problem is quite complicated unfortunately and would exceed this topic. I'll post another one when I need further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you cannot on-demand know of the classes that extend it, you can be slightly sneaky and cache anything that utilizes its constructor:

```
public class Inheritance {

    public Inheritance() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing test = new Testing();
    }

}

class Testing extends Inheritance {

    public Testing() {
        super();
    }

}
```

Would print "Testing", using the `this.getClass()` in the super constructor will return a `Class<?>` instance of the class that is extending it.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible because a class does not know who inherits it. See [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), here you can see the basic concept behind what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather easy with http://code.google.com/p/reflections/ . This snippet lists all subclasses of `JPanel`, for example:

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;

public class SubtypesReflectionsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Class<?> c = JPanel.class;
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
            "", ClasspathHelper.forClass(c),
            new SubTypesScanner(false));
        Set<?> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(c);
        for (Object element : subTypes)
        {
            System.out.println("Class "+element);
        }
    }
}
```

But I agree with the comments: You should *really* think about what you are doing there, and if there is no more appropriate way to achieve your goal.